# Finding Sub-Pixel Accurate Maxima in a 3D Image

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline

I am using a 3D cross correlation technqiue to track a particle in 3D. It is very robust but my z dimension is 4x times lower resolution than my x and y. The cross correlation produces a 3D image with a single maximum. I would like to localise this point with sub-pixel accuracy using interpolation of some sort I expect.

Any help welcome!

Craig

Answer (score 0):

You could use bicubic (tricubic in 3D?) or similar interpolation around the peak, as used for image scaling, to better localize the peak. This is commonly done in image processing, for example when localizing peaks in difference-of-gaussian stacks for blob detection, by performing a cubic approximation in each dimension, with the respective neighbouring pixels.